# python: how to rotate a line 45 degrees

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two points and plot them as a line as below picture.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
plt.plot(lont[-2:],latt[-2:],'b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

and now I want to rotated this line 45 degrees (take one of the two points as a origin)
how should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rotation looks like the following:

```
newx = (x1 - xorigin)*cos(45 * pi / 180)
newy = (y1 - yorigin)*sin(45 * pi / 180)
```

If one of your points is the origin you only need apply it to the other point

Comment: `x1` signifies what exactly?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava `(x1, y1)` are the coordinates of any given point along the original line, and `(newx, newy)` are the coordinates of that point rotated around the origin `(xorigin, yorigin)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

angle = np.deg2rad(45)
lont = pd.Series([1, 2, 4, 6])
latt = pd.Series([4, 6, 3, 2])
R = (lont.diff()**2 + latt.diff()**2)**0.5
theta = np.arctan(latt.diff()/lont.diff())

Xnew = lont.shift(1)+ R*np.cos(angle + theta)
Ynew = latt.shift(1) + R*np.sin(angle+ theta)

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(lont, latt,'-ob')
plt.plot([lont.iloc[-n-2], Xnew.iloc[-n-1]], [latt.iloc[-n-2], Ynew.iloc[-n-1]], ":*r")
plt.show()
```

[image]