# Adding a 45 degree line to a time series stock data plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I guess this is supposed to be simple.. But I cant seem to make it work.

I have some stock data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = "06/01/2018", end = "08/01/2018"),
data = np.random.rand(62)*100)
```

I am doing some analysis on it, this results of my drawing some lines on the graph.

And I want to plot a 45 line somewhere on the graph as a reference for lines I drew on the graph.

What I have tried is

```
x = df.tail(len(df)/20).index
x = x.reset_index()
x_first_val = df.loc[x.loc[0].date].adj_close
```

In order to get some point and then use slope = 1 and calculate y values.. but this sounds all wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494276/python-how-to-rotated-a-line-45-degrees) answer.

Comment: not quite.. or at least I could not figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = "06/01/2018", end = "08/01/2018"),
                  data=np.random.rand(62)*100,
                  columns=['data'])

#  Get values for the time:
index_range = df.index[('2018-06-18' < df.index)  & (df.index < '2018-07-21')]

# get the timestamps in nanoseconds (since epoch)
timestamps_ns = index_range.astype(np.int64) 
# convert it to a relative number of days (for example, could be seconds)
time_day = (timestamps_ns - timestamps_ns[0]) / 1e9 / 60 / 60 / 24  

# Define y-data for a line:
slope = 3  # unit: "something" per day
something = time_day * slope

trendline = pd.Series(something, index=index_range)

# Graph:
df.plot(label='data', alpha=0.8)
trendline.plot(label='some trend')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('something');
```

which gives:

[image: example graph]

**edit -** first answer, using `dayofyear` instead of the timestamps:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = "06/01/2018", end = "08/01/2018"),
                  data=np.random.rand(62)*100,
                  columns=['data'])

# Define data for a line:
slope = 3  # unit: "something" per day

index_range = df.index[('2018-06-18' < df.index)  & (df.index < '2018-07-21')]

dayofyear = index_range.dayofyear  #  it will not work around the new year...
dayofyear = dayofyear - dayofyear[0]
something = dayofyear * slope

trendline = pd.Series(something, index=index_range)

# Graph:
df.plot(label='data', alpha=0.8)
trendline.plot(label='some trend')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('something');
```

Comment: why slope = 3 and not 1?

Comment: also, the y axes for each stock is different. if you change in this code data=np.random.rand(62)*20, you would get a different angle. I need the line to some how depend on the y values.

Comment: @korenmaliniak you can choose, 3 is an arbitrary choice, the point is the slope has to have a physical unit: dollars per day, or kilogram per minute, this depending on your data...

Comment: If you were plotting a date versus a date, then a 45 degree line is meaningful, the slope is 1 hour per hour for example, so there is no unit... but I don't think your y-data are dates?  the unit of the slope is (unit of the y-axis)/(unit of the x-axis)... here the unit of the x-axis is time, but you also have to be careful if it is years, weeks, days, seconds, nanoseconds... etc

Comment: Ok got you. So basically, if i am fitting some line to this data (linregress). I have no way to know what is the slope of this line.. it depends on my x unis.. in my case I just resetindex so each day is 1...

Comment: but maybe it does work.. because if I do the same process to ALL stocks... bigger slope is bigger slope... am I right?

Comment: I modified my answer. The used unit of time (day, seconds...etc) in Pandas is not explicit because the index is a DateTime object. When in computation is performed on the data (regression, computing a model -in this case a line) I think it is better to do the conversion explicitly by choosing a time unit (in the example its by day, but it could be by year...)... I don't know how you perform the regression, but at some point the conversion has to be done, and the unit of the result (the slope) is given by the unit chosen for the conversion (pandas index to a list of numbers)

Comment: When doing regression I convert my X to regular range. 1 for each day.